# How to pass comma separated value to a stored procedure directly in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, split

How to pass comma separated value to a stored procedure directly in SQLSERVER?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CM_GetUnreadCount_ByUserJid_bilal_onlyfortesting] (@UserID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (
    MessageId BIGINT,
    RecieverId VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @myTable (
    MessageId,
    RecieverId
    )
SELECT MAX(MessageID),
    ReceiverID
FROM dbo.CM_MessageStatus
WHERE ReceiverID IN (@UserID)
    AND DeliveredDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ReceiverID

EXEC [CM_GetUnreadCount_ByUserJid_bilal_onlyfortesting] '123', '456'
```

**Error:**

> Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure
>   CM_GetUnreadCount_ByUserJid_bilal_onlyfortesting, Line 0 Procedure or
>   function CM_GetUnreadCount_ByUserJid_bilal_onlyfortesting has too many
>   arguments specified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write

```
exec [CM_GetUnreadCount_ByUserJid_bilal_onlyfortesting] '123,456'
```

And then you need to string_split it inside your stored procedure, just like this:

**Notice - You can only use string_split in 2016 otherwise you need to do something else like XML PATH**

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE [dbo].[CM_GetUnreadCount_ByUserJid_bilal_onlyfortesting] ( @UserID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
AS


 DECLARE @myTable TABLE
                        (
                          MessageId BIGINT,
                          RecieverId VARCHAR(100)
                        )

DECLARE @UserTable TABLE
( UserId varchar(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @UserTable (UserID)
select * from string_split(@UserID,','); 

                    INSERT INTO @myTable
                            ( MessageId, RecieverId )
                     SELECT    MAX(MessageID),RecieverID
                      FROM      dbo.Message_status
                      WHERE     RecieverID IN (select * from @UserTable)
                                AND DeliveredDate IS NOT NULL
                                GROUP BY RecieverID

                                --RETURN OUTPUT TO TEST
                                Select * from @myTable
```